# How to change Edit text font color when character limit exceeds?

Tags: android, android-edittext

[I want to change edit text color when character limit exceeds just like in this image.]

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHTCA.png]

- How to give this effect on Text Change Listener ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText + set some words in colour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303166/android-edittext-set-some-words-in-colour)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest following this link, which I believe show you how.

[Android: Different colours for different characters in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043767/android-different-colours-for-different-characters-in-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spannable` :

```
    EditText tv = (EditText )findViewById(R.id.tv);

    Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("I know just how to whisper, And I know just how to cry,I know just where to find the answers");
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Or html format `Html.fromHtml` :

```
    String text = "This is <font color='red'>red</font>. This is <font color='blue'>blue</font>.";
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try This I think this will help you:

```
if(edit_text.length> limit){edit_text.settextcolor("your color code");}
```